# Geoserver Dynamic Symbolizers with SLD and CSS not working

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

when I am applying GeoServer Style CSS for points its applying style to all the 
points and when I am binding image URL with the label there it's binding the URL string.

I am using geoserver 2.12.1

```
* {
   mark: 
url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg);
 mark-mime: "image/svg";
 mark-size: 20;
 label: [ImageUrl];
 }
```

Same when I am trying to bind dynamic URL as below it's not binding the style.

```
   * {
     mark: url("${ImageUrl}");
     mark-mime: "image/svg";
     mark-size: 20;
     label: [ImageUrl];
     }
```

same dynamic binding i have tried with Dynamic Symbolizers sld where i am passing dynamic **ImageUrl** in sld:OnlineResource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor             
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"     
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                <sld:OnlineResource 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" 
           xlink:href='${ImageUrl}'/>
                <sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
              </sld:ExternalGraphic>
              <sld:Size>20</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
          <sld:TextSymbolizer>
            <sld:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>ImageUrl</ogc:PropertyName>
            </sld:Label>
            <sld:Fill/>
          </sld:TextSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
 </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: is ImageUrl an attribute of your features or an environment variable?

Comment: yes, its an attribute of my features